# Cannot interpret 'CategoricalDtype'

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data

I would like to split variables into the different types. For example:

```
Tweets   ID    Registration Date   num_unique_words   photo_profile  range
object  int64  object              float64             int64         category
```

What I did is:

`type_dct = {str(k): list(v) for k, v in df.groupby(df.dtypes, axis=1)}` but I have got a TypeError:

```
TypeError: Cannot interpret 'CategoricalDtype(categories=['<5',
 '>=5'], ordered=True)' as a data type
```

`range` can take two values: '<5' and '>=5'.

I hope you can help to handle this error.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Tweets': ['Tweet 1 from user 1', 'Tweet 2 from user 1', 
                              'Tweet 1 from user 3', 'Tweet 10 from user 1'], 
                   'ID': [124, 124, 12, 124], 
                   'Registration Date': ['2020-12-02', '2020-11-21', 
                                         '2020-12-02', '2020-12-02'], 
                   'num_unique_words': [41, 42, 12, 69], 
                   'photo_profile': [1, 0, 1, 1], 
                   'range': ['<5', '<5', '>=5', '<5']}, 
                  index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])
```

Comment: Thanks @Arne. I did not notice the error. Thank you for fixing it :) It is weird that you are not receiving the error. I am still having that error. Unfortunately I do not know what is causing that error. I have no null values in that column.

Comment: I guess you did something in between assigning `df` and `type_dct` as shown above. Did you specifically cast `range` as a `pd.CategoricalDtype`? If you did anything like that, it would help to see that part of your code too.

Comment: no, actually I did not. I am passing this df, with no changes (it is just a sample in my question, but I have checked and there are no NaN values. Unique values are <5 ad >=5.

Comment: What happens if you explicitly set `df['range'] = df['range'].astype("object")` before creating the type dictionary?

Comment: I think it was a bug. Now it works fine. Thanks, Arne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update:

That was surprisingly more complicated that I thought it would be, but here is a work around using list comprehension:

```
type_dct = {str(k): list(v) for k, v in df.groupby([i.name for i in df.dtypes], axis=1)}
```

Output:

```
{'category': ['range'],
 'int64': ['ID', 'num_unique_words', 'photo_profile'],
 'object': ['Tweets', 'Registration Date']}
```

pd.CategorialDtypes by itself doesn't work well in the groupby, we must use the name attribute of that object.

---

Use [`pd.DataFrame.select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html)

Example from docs.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2] * 3,
                   'b': [True, False] * 3,
                   'c': [1.0, 2.0] * 3})
df
        a      b  c
0       1   True  1.0
1       2  False  2.0
2       1   True  1.0
3       2  False  2.0
4       1   True  1.0
5       2  False  2.0
df.select_dtypes(include='bool')
   b
0  True
1  False
2  True
3  False
4  True
5  False
df.select_dtypes(include=['float64'])
   c
0  1.0
1  2.0
2  1.0
3  2.0
4  1.0
5  2.0
df.select_dtypes(exclude=['int64'])
       b    c
0   True  1.0
1  False  2.0
2   True  1.0
3  False  2.0
4   True  1.0
5  False  2.0
```

Comment: thanks Scott Boston. How could I add this information on separate lists? I would need to consider objects types, boolean and numerical variables into three different lists, if possible

Comment: @Val, would you include code to generate your dataframe in this problem, that way I can show you exactly how to separate our your given dataframe based on dtype of columns.

Comment: please see the updated question. Thank you so much. Let me know if you need more information